# Hostname different from ip address

Tags: networking, dns, ip, hostname

I have two VMs in a private cloud. Lets call them A(1.2.3.90) and B (1.2.3.91) (not actual ips). I used one of them(A) as a template and cloned the second one(B) only changing the ips (static ips).

From my local machine on the network, I am able to ping both 90 & 91.
Even running `ip a` on both machines give the correct Ip addresses.

I even checked `/etc/hosts` and the info is correct.

However, when i run `hostname -i` or `hostname -f` on the machine with Ip as 91, I get the result as `1.2.3.90`.

I suspect this has something to do with the cloning process.

My question is however, How do i fix the issue on machine 2(1.2.3.91)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the content of `/etc/hostname`? Have you tried using `hostnamectl --set-hostname B` to change the hostname/IP?

Comment: i manually changed the contents of `/etc/hostname`. I did not believe that was the right way to do stuff which is why i asked the question.

But the command you suggested worked, but i believe the option does not have the leading double hyphen. Its `hostnamectl set-hostname B`.